# java to format date and to return it as date object

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I have a pojo class in which one of the field is date. Here I am using hibernate to insert values into the db using these pojos.

I have set the current date value for this property and I am inserting the value to the DB. Here I need to generate the insert script programaticaly. I have done this and i am printing the insert statement in the console. But while printing in the console the date is shown as **Fri Jun 07 04:49:07 ACT 2013** and the insert statement is

```
INSERT INTO tables (dates)values('Fri Jun 07 04:49:07 ACT 2013');
```

I don't want to generate the script like this i need it as

```
INSERT INTO tables (dates)values('2013-06-07');
```

I know We can use simple date formatter but i need this as  date to set the POJO value. So if it is String it will not be set into the object.

I am forming the query as below

```
    StringBuffer columnName = new StringBuffer();
    columnName.append("insert into Tables values ('"+obj.getdates()+"')");
```

Before i used logger and at that time the query was formed and i think hibernate took care of that formatting because after inserting the query was formed as

```
INSERT INTO tables (dates)values('2013-06-07');
```

But now by hardcoding it is giving the above query whcih is not getting executed as the date value is not correct.

Can anyone help me here. Also in the case of hibernate whether formatting is done by hibernate or at the backend whether it is converting automatically

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to insert the date as `String`? Your JDBC driver should be able to insert this as `Date`.

Comment: So you're in fact using JDBC to insert data, and not Hibernate, right? If so use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). If using Hibernate, then just create instances of your entities and persist them.

Comment: It is REALLY bad form to build your SQL as a concatenated String or even a StringBuffer/StringBuilder.  You should be using parameter substitution, either by placing '?' where the substitution occurs, or using a map parameter with labels for the substitution.

Comment: We need to generate the sql insert statements before peforming insert in the table . it is a choise from the client side. Either they will use the automated insertion through hibernate which is already done and the other is to generate the sql scripts in a file and they will use these scripts for the insertion  manually. While genrating the JDBC driver is not converting it into the date as the formatted manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your date into java.sql.Date

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);
```